# Multiple Joins in Django

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, django-1.8

I'm trying to convert following SQL query to Django ORM but failing to do this.

SQL Query

```
select distinct(cch.campaign_contact_id), cc.lead_status, cc.contact_id, c.*, ls.date, ls.token from campaign_contact_history as cch left join campaign_contacts as cc on cc.id=cch.campaign_contact_id left join contacts as c on c.id=cc.contact_id left join leadsummary as ls on ls.contact_id=c.id where cc.lead_status in ('8', '9') and cch.created_at between '2018-01-01' and '2018-10-20';
```

**Here is the explanation what above query does in the context of SQL:**

It will get all columns from `Contact` model and one column from `CampaignContact` model i.e. `lead_status` and one column from `LeadSummary` model i.e. `date`.
Based on `CampaignContactHistory` model a filter has to apply for `created_at` range and `distinct campaign_contact`.

**Here is the explanation what above query does in the context of ORM:**
Based on `CampaignContactHistory` model I want all objects from `Contact` and also from `CampaignContact`, `LeadSummary`. It will apply a filter on `created_at` on `CampaignContactHistory` using distinct() on `campaign_contact` object which is in `CampaignContactHistory`.

Here are the Models defined:

```
class CampaignContactHistory(DateAwareModel):  # campaign_contact_history
    campaign_contact = models.ForeignKey(CampaignContact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lead_status = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class CampaignContact(DateAwareModel):  # campaign_contacts
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lead_status = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Contact(DateAwareModel):  # contacts
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    contact_UID = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...

class LeadSummary(DateAwareModel):  # leadsummary
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

The table names which I have used in SQL Query are written as comments in front of every class model.

Please help me to solve this problem. Also if anyone can suggest me to improve my `SQL Query` that would be much better.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are trying to replicate SQL queries in the Django ORM you will most likely find yourself lost. So, please explain what you are trying to do with the models!

Comment: Ok Sure... I'll edit my question and add what are the operations I need.

Comment: @KlausD. added explanation. Please tell me if you get this otherwise I'll try to edit more.

Comment: You are still thinking in SQL. You should ask something like: I want all `Contact` objects that match a criteria and its related `CampaignContact` objects.